# this.state.display && <h1>Displayed!</h1> works but not vice versa?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I only want to display h1 element if this.state.display is true.

```
{this.state.display && <h1>Displayed!</h1> }
```

works, but

```
{<h1>Displayed!</h1> && this.state.display}
```

does not. I am testing it out on here:
https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/react/use-a-ternary-expression-for-conditional-rendering

Anyone know the reason why?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` means "If the left side is truthy, then return the right side. Otherwise (if the left side is falsy), then return the left side." Since `<h1>Displayed!</h1>` is truthy, that unconditionally evaluates to `this.state.display`, which isn't what you want to render.